# Why are joins bad when considering scalability?

Tags: sql, join

Why are joins bad or 'slow'. I know i heard this more then once. I found this quote

> The problem is joins are relatively
>   slow, especially over very large data
>   sets, and if they are slow your
>   website is slow. It takes a long time
>   to get all those separate bits of
>   information off disk and put them all
>   together again.

[source](http://highscalability.com/scaling-secret-2-denormalizing-your-way-speed-and-profit)

I always thought they were fast especially when looking up a PK. Why are they 'slow'?

Answer (score 121, accepted):

Scalability is all about pre-computing (caching), spreading out, or paring down the repeated work to the bare essentials, in order to minimize resource use per work unit. To scale well, you don't do anything you don't need to in volume, and the things you actually do you make sure are done as efficiently as possible.

In that context, of course joining two separate data sources is relatively slow, at least compared to not joining them, because it's work you need to do live at the point where the user requests it.

But remember the alternative is no longer having two separate pieces of data at all; you have to put the two disparate data points in the same record. You can't combine two different pieces of data without a consequence somewhere, so make sure you understand the trade-off.

The good news is modern relational databases are *good* at joins. You shouldn't really think of joins as slow with a good database used well. There are a number of scalability-friendly ways to take raw joins and make them *much* faster:

- Join on a surrogate key (autonumer/identity column) rather than a natural key. This means smaller (and therefore faster) comparisons during the join operation
- Indexes
- Materialized/indexed views (think of this as a pre-computed join or *managed* de-normalization)
- Computed columns. You can use this to hash or otherwise pre-compute the key columns of a join, such that what would be a complicated comparison for a join is now much smaller and potentially pre-indexed.
- Table partitions (helps with large data sets by spreading the load out to multiple disks, or limiting what might have been a table scan down to a partition scan)
- OLAP (pre-computes results of certain kinds of queries/joins. It's not quite true, but you can think of this as *generic* denormalization)
- Replication, Availability Groups, Log shipping, or other mechanisms to let multiple servers answer read queries for the same database, and thus scale your workload out among several servers.
- Use of a caching layer like Redis to avoid re-running queries which need complex joins.

I would go as far as saying **the main reason relational databases exist at all is to allow you do joins efficiently**<sup>*</sup>. It's certainly not just to store structured data (you could do that with flat file constructs like csv or xml). A few of the options I listed will even let you completely build your join in advance, so the results are already done before you issue the query — just as if you had denormalized the data (admittedly at the cost of slower write operations).

**If you have a slow join, you're probably not using your database correctly.**

De-normalization should be done only after these other techniques have failed. And the only way you can truly judge "failure" is to set meaningful performance goals and measure against those goals. *If you haven't measured, it's too soon to even think about de-normalization.*

---

<sub>* That is, exist as entities distinct from mere collections of tables.  An additional reason for a real rdbms is safe concurrent access.</sub>

Comment: Indexes should probably be at the top of the list. A lot of (*cough*) developers seem to forget about them when testing on a small data set and then bring the database to its knees in production. I have seen queries that run to the order of 100,000 times faster simply by adding indexes. And that's arbitrary indexes without even doing any in-depth data analysis to determine the best mix for leftmost prefix matching.

Comment: I think I have the order about right- it's just most developers already do the first item, and so indexes is the first item where they'll need to make changes.

Comment: In your third item, you mention "Materialized/indexed views".  Are you talking about regular SQL views, or something else?

Comment: @slolife regular sql views are like running an extra query in the background on the fly when you use a query that references the view.  But you can also tell sql server to "materialize" some views. When you do this, sql server will keep an extra copy of the view's data, just like a regular table, such that when you reference the view in a query it no longer has to run this query in the background because the data is already there.  You can also put different indexes on the view than the source table, to further help you tune performance.

Comment: I'm new to RDBMS tuning, but this point makes me wonder: "If you have a slow join, you're probably not using your database correctly." Isn't there a limit to the size of tables that can be joined efficiently? E.g., joining four tables with 10^6 rows each.  Curious to hear your thoughts.

Comment: @MatthewCornell This is what indexes are for. If you are joining four tables of that size, and the join is not performing well, look at the join conditions and consider adding an index for some of the columns in the condition. This will help the database efficiently ignore records that have no chance to be included in the results.

Comment: can you give us an example of a DB that is open source that support Materialized/indexed views? what is the name they use for it? i know mysql does not support it

Comment: @Toskan Old now, but Postgresql supports this. In more opinion, MySql doesn't really qualify as a modern DB engine any more. It hasn't kept pace with features added to the other big databases: materialized views, CTEs, APPLY/LATERAL JOIN, Windowing Functions... I could go on. Many of things things have been more or less standard in other DBs for over a decade, but MySql has stagnated since around 2004, even before the Oracle acquisition, and only recently begun to address some (not all) of these.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn so the word is materialized views still? the thing is, mysql is still the best supported DB in most frameworks and libraries. Yes yes, postgresql can do more. But if it doesn't work well with some lib, then why bother. Sure, a fully fledged multi million dollar project where everything or a lot is self written, different story.

Comment: Depending on the database type it may also be called in an Indexed View

Answer (score 30):

Joins can be **slower** than avoiding them through de-normalisation but if used correctly (joining on columns with appropriate indexes an so on) **they are not inherently slow**.

De-normalisation is one of many optimisation techniques you can consider if your well designed database schema exhibits performance problems.

Comment: ...except in MySQL, which seems to have performance problems with large numbers of joins regardless of how your indexes look.  Or at least it has in the past.

Comment: Point taken, if there are known issues with the specific DBMS (and perhaps even version) then this advice may make sense, but as general advice it is pretty misleading if you are using a relational database. That said non-relational storage mechanisms are becoming more popular Amazon's SimpleDB and CouchDB (http://couchdb.apache.org/) are examples. If you are better served by leaving the relational model behind you should probably leave the products that optimised for the behind too and look for other tools.

Answer (score 14):

article says that they are slow when compared to absence of joins. this can be achieved with denormalization. so there is a trade off between speed and normalization. don't forget about premature optimization also :)

Comment: even this is not a hard rule, if you join on a table, mysql might use an index to perform that join - that index join could prune many rows, and another index for any where clause on the tables. If you don't join, mysql will typically use only one index(which might not be the most efficient one), no matter how your where clause is formed.

Answer (score 14):

First of all, a relational database's raison d'etre (reason for being) is to be able to model relationships between entities.  Joins are simply the mechanisms by which we traverse those relationships.  They certainly do come at a nominal cost, but without joins, there really is no reason to have a relational database.

In the academic world we learn of things like the various normal forms (1st, 2nd, 3rd, Boyce-Codd, etc.), and we learn about different types of keys (primary, foreign, alternate, unique, etc.) and how these things fit together to design a database.  And we learn the rudiments of SQL as well as manipulating both structure and data (DDL & DML).

In the corporate world, many of the academic constructs turn out to be substantially less viable than we had been led to believe.  A perfect example is the notion of a primary key.  Academically it is that attribute (or collection of attributes) that uniquely identifies one row in the table.  So in many problem domains, the proper academic primary key is a composite of 3 or 4 attributes.  However, almost everyone in the modern corporate world uses an auto-generated, sequential integer as a table's primary key.  Why?  Two reasons.  The first is because it makes the model much cleaner when you're migrating FKs all over the place.  The second, and most germane to this question, is that retrieving data through joins is faster and more efficient on a single integer than it is on 4 varchar columns (as already mentioned by a few folks).

Let's dig a little deeper now into two specific subtypes of real world databases.  The first type is a transactional database.  This is the basis for many e-commerce or content management applications driving modern sites.  With a transaction DB, you're optimizing heavily toward "transaction throughput".  Most commerce or content apps have to balance query performance (from certain tables) with insert performance (in other tables), though each app will have its own unique business driven issues to solve.

The second type of real world database is a reporting database.  These are used almost exclusively to aggregate business data and to generate meaningful business reports.  They are typically shaped differently than the transaction databases where the data is generated and they are highly optimized for speed of bulk data loading (ETLs) and query performance with large or complex data sets.

In each case, the developer or DBA needs to carefully balance both the functionality and performance curves, and there are lots of performance enhancing tricks on both sides of the equation.  In Oracle you can do what's called an "explain plan" so you can see specifically how a query gets parsed and executed.  You're looking to maximize the DB's proper use of indexes.  One really nasty no-no is to put a function in the where clause of a query.  Whenever you do that, you guarantee that Oracle will not use any indexes on that particular column and you'll likely see a full or partial table scan in the explain plan.  That's just one specific example of how a query could be written that ends up being slow, and it doesn't have anything to do with joins.

And while we're talking about table scans, they obviously impact the query speed proportionally to the size of the table.  A full table scan of 100 rows isn't even noticeable.  Run that same query on a table with 100 million rows, and you'll need to come back next week for the return.

Let's talk about normalization for a minute.  This is another largely positive academic topic that can get over-stressed.  Most of the time when we talk about normalization we really mean the elimination of duplicate data by putting it into its own table and migrating an FK.  Folks usually skip over the whole dependence thing described by 2NF and 3NF.  And yet in an extreme case, it's certainly possible to have a perfect BCNF database that's enormous and a complete beast to write code against because it's so normalized.

So where do we balance?  There is no single best answer.  All of the better answers tend to be some compromise between ease of structure maintenance, ease of data maintenance and ease of code creation/maintenance.  In general, the less duplication of data, the better.

So why are joins sometimes slow?  Sometimes it's bad relational design.  Sometimes it's ineffective indexing.  Sometimes it's a data volume issue.  Sometimes it's a horribly written query.

Sorry for such a long-winded answer, but I felt compelled to provide a meatier context around my comments rather than just rattle off a 4-bullet response.

Answer (score 13):

People with terrabyte sized databases still use joins, if they can get them to work performance-wise then so can you.

There are many reasons not to denomalize. First, speed of select queries is not the only or even main concern with databases. Integrity of the data is the first concern. If you denormalize then you have to put into place techniques to keep the data denormalized as the parent data changes. So suppose you take to storing the client name in all tables instead of joining to the client table on the client_Id. Now when the name of the client changes (100% chance some of the names of clients will change over time), now you need to update all the child records to reflect that change. If you do this wil a cascade update and you have a million child records, how fast do you suppose that is going to be and how many users are going to suffer locking issues and delays in their work while it happens? Further most people who denormalize because "joins are slow" don't know enough about databases to properly make sure their data integrity is protected and often end up with databases that have unuseable data becasue the integrity is so bad.

Denormalization is a complex process that requires an thorough understanding of database performance and integrity if it is to be done correctly. Do not attempt to denormalize unless you have such expertise on staff.

Joins are quite fast enough if you do several things. First use a suggorgate key, an int join is almost alawys the fastest join. Second always index the foreign key.  Use derived tables or join conditions to create a smaller dataset to filter on.  If you have a large very complex database, then hire a professional database person with experience in partioning and managing huge databases. There are plenty of techniques to improve performance without getting rid of joins.

If you just need query capability, then yes you can design a datawarehouse which can be denormalized and is populated through an ETL tool (optimized for speed) not user data entry.

Answer (score 9):

Joins are slow if

- the data is improperly indexed
- results poorly filtered
- joining query poorly written
- data sets very large and complex

So, true, the bigger your data sets the the more processing you'll need for a query but checking and working on the first three options of the above will often yield great results.

Your source gives denormalization as an option. This is fine only as long as you've exhausted better alternatives.

Answer (score 8):

`Joins are fast.` Joins should be considered standard practice with a properly normalized database schema. Joins allow you to join disparate groups of data in a meaningful way. Don't fear the join.

The caveat is that you must understand normalization, joining, and the proper use of indexes.

Beware premature optimization, as the number one failing of all development projects is meeting the deadline. Once you've completed the project, and you understand the trade offs, you can break the rules if you can justify it.

It's true that join performance degrades non-linearly as the size of the data set increases. Therefore, it doesn't scale as nicely as single table queries, but it still does scale.

It's also true that a bird flies faster without any wings, but only straight down.

Answer (score 7):

The joins can be slow if large portions of records from each side need to be scanned.

Like this:

```
SELECT  SUM(transaction)
FROM    customers
JOIN    accounts
ON      account_customer = customer_id
```

Even if an index is defined on `account_customer`, all records from the latter still need to be scanned.

For the query list this, the decent optimizers won't probably even consider the index access path, doing a `HASH JOIN` or a `MERGE JOIN` instead.

Note that for a query like this:

```
SELECT  SUM(transaction)
FROM    customers
JOIN    accounts
ON      account_customer = customer_id
WHERE   customer_last_name = 'Stellphlug'
```

the join will most probably will be fast: first, an index on `customer_last_name` will be used to filter all Stellphlug's (which are of course, not very numerous), then an index scan on `account_customer` will be issued for each Stellphlug to find his transactions.

Despite the fact that these can be billions of records in `accounts` and `customers`, only few will actually need to be scanned.

Comment: but it is hard to avoid it. design your app so that this kind of queries are not executed too often.

Comment: If an index is defined on `accounts(account_customer)` most RDBMSes would use that index to find out exactly which rows of the `customers` database need be scanned.

Comment: yes, but it is not cheap operation anyway. you can store sum in some field and update in on each transaction.

Comment: @jemfinch: no, they won't. This would require scanning the whole index just to filter out the customers, then scanning customer's index in a nested loop. A `HASH JOIN` would be much faster so it's what will be used except in all major databases except `MySQL`, which will just make `customers` leading in a nested loop (since it's smaller in size)

Answer (score 3):

Properly designed tables containing with the proper indicies and correctly written queries not always slow.  Where ever you heard that:

> Why are joins bad or 'slow'

has no idea what they are talking about!!!  Most joins will be very fast.  If you have to join many many rows at one time you might take a hit as compared to a denormalized table, but that goes back to Properly designed tables, know when to denormalize and when not to.  in a heavy reporting system, break out the data in denormalized tables for reports, or even create a data warehouse.  In a transactional heavy system normalize the tables.

Answer (score 3):

Joins do require extra processing since they have to look in more files and more indexes to "join" the data together. However, "very large data sets" is all relative. What is the definition of large? I the case of JOINs, I think its a reference to a large result set, not that overall dataset.

Most databases can very quickly process a query that selects 5 records from a primary table and joins 5 records from a related table for each record (assuming the correct indexes are in place). These tables can have hundreds of millions of records each, or even billions.

Once your result set starts growing, things are going to slow down. Using the same example, if the primary table results in 100K records, then there will be 500K "joined" records that need to be found. Just pulling that much data out of the database with add delays.

Don't avoid JOINs, just know you may need to optimize/denormalize when datasets get "very large".

Answer (score 3):

Also from the article you cited:

> Many mega-scale websites with billions
>   of records, petabytes of data, many
>   thousands of simultaneous users, and
>   millions of queries a day are doing is
>   using a sharding scheme and some are
>   even advocating denormalization as the
>   best strategy for architecting the
>   data tier.

and

> And unless you are a really large
>   website you probably don't need to
>   worry about this level of complexity.

and

> It's more error prone than having the
>   database do all this work, but you are
>   able to do scale past what even the
>   highest end databases can handle.

The article is discussing mega-sites like Ebay.  At that level of usage you are likely going to have to consider something other than plain vanilla relational database management.  But in the "normal" course of business (applications with thousands of users and millions of records) those more expensive, more error prone approaches are overkill.

Answer (score 2):

Joins are considered an opposing force to scalability because they're typically the bottleneck and they cannot be easily distributed or paralleled.

Comment: I'm not sure this is true.  I know Teradata is certainly able to distribute joins amongst Amps.  Obviously certain types of joins may be trickier/intractable than others.

Comment: indexes can be partitioned in RDBMS ranging from mysql to oracle. AFAIK that scales (is distributed and can be paralleled).

Answer (score 1):

The amount of temporary data that is generated could be huge based on the joins.

For an example, one database here at work had a generic search function where all of the fields were optional.  The search routine did a join on every table before the search began.  This worked well in the beginning.  But, now that the main table has over 10 million rows... not so much.  Searches now take 30 minutes or more.

I was tasked with optimizing the search stored procedure.

The first thing I did was if any of the fields of the main table were being searched, I did a select to a temp table on those fields only.  THEN, I joined all the tables with that temp table before doing the rest of the search.  Searches where one of the main table fields now take less than 10 seconds.

If none of the main table fields are begin searched, I do similar optimizations for other tables.  When I was done, no search takes longer than 30 seconds with most under 10.

CPU utilization of the SQL server also went WAY DOWN.

Comment: @BoltBait: Is the take-away message that you should always try to reduce the number of rows before you perform a join?

Comment: It certainly worked wonders in my case. But, I wouldn't optimize a system until it becomes necessary.

Comment: normally no temporary data is generated on joins (depending of course on selectivity, available memory and size of join buffers), AFAIK; however the temporary data is typically created on order by and distinct if there is no index that can be used for such operations.

Answer (score 1):

While joins (presumably due to a normalized design) can obviously be slower for data retrieval than a read from a single table, a denormalized database can be slow for data creation/update operations since the footprint of the overall transaction will not be minimal.

In a normalized database, a piece of data will live in only one place, so the footprint for an update will be as minimal as possible.  In a denormalized database, it's possible that the same column in multiple rows or across tables will have to be updated, meaning the footprint would be larger and chance of locks and deadlocks can increase.

Answer (score 1):

Well, yeah, selecting rows from one denormalized table (assuming decent indexes for your query) might be faster that selecting rows constructed from joining several tables, particularly if the joins don't have efficient indexes available.

The examples cited in the article - Flickr and eBay - are exceptional cases IMO, so have (and deserve) exceptional responses.  The author specifically calls out the lack of RI and the extent of data duplication in the article.

Most applications - again, IMO - benefit from the validation & reduced duplication provided by RDBMSs.

Answer (score 0):

They can be slow if done sloppily. For example, if you do a 'select *' on a join you will probaby take a while to get stuff back. However, if you carefully choose what columns to return from each table, and with the proper indexes in place, there should be no problem.